# Where does Navicat store its license file on a mac?

Tags: macos, mac

I want to completely remove Navicat from my system. Where does Navicat store its license files?

Answer (score 10):

the license data is located in:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.prect.Navicat<edition>.plist
```

supporting files are stored in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/PremiumSoft CyberTech
```